# Python/Django - String not accepted ('Expected a string or bytes-like object)

Tags: python, django

At the end of a form wizard, I have a custom save for an object:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

    (...)

    start = datetime.strptime(self.request.session['event_start'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    duration = datetime.strptime(self.request.session['duration'], '%H:%M:%S').time()

    EventInstance.objects.create(
        event=event_obj,
        start=start,
        duration=duration,
        recurring='0F',
    )

    (...)
```

I've manually written a string in for the final step, to try and isolate the problem. When I try to run the final script, the traceback highlights the `recurring` field with a `TypeError` and tells me that Python `expected string or bytes-like object`.

This is my model:

```
class EventInstance(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DateTimeField()
    recurring = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

`event_obj` is an `Event` object that I created earlier in the process. Can someone help me understand this error?

Traceback here:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py" in dispatch
  237.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Documents\otherlane\Otherlane\Events\views.py" in post
  181.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\formtools\wizard\views.py" in render_done
  357.                                   **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Documents\otherlane\Otherlane\Events\views.py" in done
  239.             recurring='0F',
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  348.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  846.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  885.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  973.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  931.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  931.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  929.                     ) for f in fields
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  710.                                       prepared=False)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  1482.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1461.         value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1317.         return self.to_python(value)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in to_python
  1420.             parsed = parse_datetime(value)
File "C:\Users\Zeratul\Envs\otherlane\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py" in parse_datetime
  93.     match = datetime_re.match(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /events/post_event/
Exception Value: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at the traceback, it seems to be an issue with the "Duration" field. Perhaps because I am trying to save a time as a datetime object?

```
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   <class 'django.db.models.fields.DateField'>
value   datetime.time(0, 30)
self    <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: duration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's highlighted on the last line, but it's obvious that by tracing the stack it ends up in django's `dateparse.py` file, which indicates that it's related to `datetime` issues not correctly parsed. Traceback would only highlight a complete statement but since your `create` function is a multi-line statement, it marks on the `recurring='0F'` line. In other words, it tells you that your statement `EventInstance.objects.create(......)` is problematic.

I believe that your `duration` field is `DateTimeField`, but your `duration` variable is a `datetime.time` object. You can't feed a `time` object to `datetime` field obviously.

The solution is easy, change `duration` field to `TimeField`.

Django doc about [`TimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#timefield).

Comment: That was it! Thank you! The traceback was confusing me, but I understand why now.

Comment: Glad that it helped. One advice, I edited your question by moving your traceback in the body of the question instead of a link. Don't rely on other website services because they might go down. Stackoverflow display traceback nicely and let others see it immediately so they could benefit from your question as well.